# Align profile header bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to center a profile header bar that I have on my website. I obtained the code script from another and have been editing the css. The header bar resembles what FB has (profile avatar and cover image which I deleted) and I dont care for it..reached out to the creator of the script and was told to research. Here is the code:

```css
.profile-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-header-options {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.profile-header-avatar {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.profile-header-avatar img {
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-header-name {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 180px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.profile-header-bar {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.profile-header-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

.profile-header-bar ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.profile-header-bar .active a {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header" style="">
  <div class="profile-header-avatar">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>/<?php echo $this->settings->info->upload_path_relative ?>/<?php echo $user->avatar ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="profile-header-name">
    <?php echo $user->first_name ?>
    <?php echo $user->last_name ?>
    <?php if($user->verified) : ?><img src="images/ck.png" width="14" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo lang(" ctn_695 ") ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="profile-header-bar clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="<?php echo site_url(" profile/ " . $user->username) ?>">
        <?php echo lang("ctn_200") ?>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url(" profile/friends/ " . $user->ID) ?>">
        <?php echo lang("ctn_493") ?>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo site_url(" profile/albums/ " . $user->ID) ?>">
        <?php echo lang("ctn_483") ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Hope someone can help, Thank ya so very much!!!
Meka

Comment: pls share html code. we need working example

Comment: Need more information, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you please provide your code in the snippet?

Comment: Hey folks I edited the post..hopefully that will help with coming up with an answer :)

Comment: please remove the php stuff and make it valid html to work with.